# (laravel) supply mocked data to view when testing?

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit

Suppose I have a blade template:

```
// resources/views/fragments/foo.blade.php
<p>{{ $foo }}</p>
```

(This is obviously a very stripped-down version of my question. I can't see why I'd ever need to test a blade template that simple.) In my controller, I would normally populate that template like this:

```
// app/Http/Controllers/FooController.php
$parameters = ['foo' => ''];
return view('fragments.foo', $parameters);
```

The problem is I'd like to write a phpunit test to ensure that template renders successfully when I pass it a specific value for `$foo`, but I can't figure out how to send data to the view when running the unit test. I tried this:

```
// tests/TestFooController.php
$this->withSession(['foo' => 'bar'])->visit('/foo')->assertViewHas('foo', 'bar');
```

but that test failed. How can I pass my own data to the view from within my test?

Answer (score 0):

Finally googled around enough to get a workaround:

```
// tests/TestFooController.php
$parameters = ['foo' => 'bar'];
view()->composer('fragments.foo', function ($view) use ($parameters) {
    $view->with($parameters);
});
$this->visit('/foo')
    ->assertViewHasAll([
        'foo' => 'bar',
    ]);
```

The cool thing (depending on how much independence you like when testing) is that if my `FooController` passes other variables, but I only override one of them in the test's view composer, the other non-overridden values will still be there.